# errorplacement jquery not showing custom messages

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using

```
   $("#myForm").validate({
     errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            checkedUserId: {
                required: true
            },
            url: {
               url: true
            },
            messages: { 
                name: "Please enter name ." ,
                checkedUserId: "Please select at least one user"
            },
            errorElement: "div",
            wrapper: "div",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                offset = element.offset();
                error.insertBefore(element)
                error.addClass('message');  // add a class to the wrapper
                error.css('position', 'absolute');
                error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
                error.css('top', offset.top);
            }
        }
 });
```

Its showing me default messages "This field is required." instead of message I want to show "Please enter name ."

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: solution added, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format your properties is incorrect, It should be:

```
rules: {

},
messages: {

}
```

Try the below code, it will work (Tested in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHpDK/)):

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        checkedUserId: {
            required: true
        },
        url: {
            url: true
        },
        errorElement: "div",
        wrapper: "div",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.insertBefore(element)
            error.addClass('message'); // add a class to the wrapper
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
            error.css('top', offset.top);
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter name .",
        checkedUserId: "Please select at least one user"
    },
});
```

Comment: That is still pretty wrong - nothing after the `url` object should be inside the rules object.  Those are all top level options (`errorElement`, `wrapper`, `errorPlacement`) - see this http://jsfiddle.net/bHpDK/1/